Cartier divisors on reduced Noetherian schemes “described” by integral open sets
I'm currently reading Olivier Debarre's book “Higher-Dimensional Algebraic Geometry” and I'm stuck on a small remark made in the definition of Cartier divisors (it's on page 3 if you have the book). Note that here, all schemes are Noetherian and separated (this is an assumption made earlier). To be precise, I can't prove the passage in bold :

A Cartier divisor on a scheme $X$ is a collection of pairs $(U_i, f_i)$, where $(U_i)$ is an open cover of $X$ and $f_i$ an invertible element of $\mathcal K_X(U_i)$ (the sheaf of total quotient rings of $\mathcal O_X$), such that $f_i / f_j$ is in $\mathcal O_X^*(U_i \cap U_j)$. When $X$ is reduced, we may take integral open sets $U_i$ (...).

I am not able to build these integral open sets. I've tried to “play” with the finitely many irreducible components of X and the assumption of $X$ being reduced, but it doesn't seem obvious to me. All $U_i$ are reduced and Noetherian too, so I tried to look at the irreducible components of these open sets to cobble something together, but it came to nothing. Do you have any ideas?

You can try proving the following statement: $X$ is an integral scheme if and only if $X$ is irreducible and reduced.

@jhzg Hey, thanks for your answer. I do know this property but I'm not sure how to apply it in this case. If $X$ is integral, of course, it is straightforward. Could you please tell me a little more about it?

$X$ is reduced, so every irreducible component of $X$ is also reduced. Hence, each irreducible component of $X$ is an integral scheme. Naturally, we can consider Cartier divisors on each irreducible component.

The components of X are always integral since, usually, we equip them with the reduced structure (even when X is a non-reduced scheme). I don't get your point.

Sorry, I made a mistake. My teacher said that more conditions are needed here; otherwise, the conclusion is incorrect.

Thanks. That's what I thought too. In his online notes “Introduction to Mori theory”, O. Debarre has replaced “reduced” with “integral”. This seems to confirm the hypothesis of a typo in the book.
